# CodeIgniter reCaptcha Trouble

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, captcha, recaptcha

Okay all, I have seen similar questions asked on this site, but they don't have all the handholding details I'm looking for on this particular issue!

I am in limbo between using the JS version of reCaptcha and a PHP version made for CodeIgniter 1.7.1

With the JS version I have it displayed within the generated HTML but I'm not sure how to get the proper result passed through to the PHP form. The surrounding form currently only posts in the PHP whether there was "any" text input, not if it was proper text. I can monitor the captcha text input field to see if anything was submitted, but this doesn't check the actual javascript for a proper result. I need a PHP function call that can get a call from the HTML that the javascript generates with Recaptcha.create.

You might be thinking: Since codeigniter is PHP why not just use the PHP version of recaptcha? Well the CodeIgniter structure is the most unintuitive PHP and MVC structure I've dealt with. Finding the necessary function calls on this site I am editing has turned into a reverse engineering exercise.

I also have a PHP version, made here https://github.com/seanmcgary/Codeigniter-ReCaptcha, and just like in classic CodeIgniter flavor, the documentation is basically nonexistent. I know that version is for CodeIgniter 1.7, but I don't know what version of reCaptcha it is.

Please don't link me to the codeigniter wiki, just relevant assistance.

It is becoming convoluted to work on implementing the JS version, and parts of a PHP version because one version *might* be more practical. So I'm asking you guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This wiki article and library are extremely simple](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA/). Because you don't want just a link here is some sample code from the wiki article to get you started.

The code is really quite self explanatory. Set up your config with your public and private keys, then in your controller load the recaptcha & form_validation libraries and show the proper view depending on the status of the validation.

**config/recaptcha:**

```
$config['recaptcha'] = array(
  'public'=>'YOUR PUBLIC KEY',
  'private'=>'YOUR PRIVATE KEY',
  'RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER' =>'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api',
  'RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER'=>'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api',
  'RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER' =>'www.google.com',
  'RECAPTCHA_SIGNUP_URL' => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create',
  'theme' => 'white'
);
```

**controller:**

```
function index()
  {
    $this->load->library('recaptcha');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->lang->load('recaptcha');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
      $this->load->view('recaptcha_demo',array('recaptcha'=>'Yay! You got it right!'));
    }
    else
    {
      //the desired language code string can be passed to the get_html() method
      //"en" is the default if you don't pass the parameter
      //valid codes can be found here:http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html#i18n
      $this->load->view('recaptcha_demo',array('recaptcha'=>$this->recaptcha->get_html()));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay, I have that set up already but I'm not sure how that works with the rest of the form. There is a name field, email, phone number - these are checked to see if there is any content in them, I need the condition to also get the value from the recaptcha code.  Can I just copy the $this->load->library functions?   Also I don't have anything in a folder named helper or a file named form in that nonexistant folder

Comment: The form helper is [a built in helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html). I'm getting the impression you don't understand how the [form validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) class works. You need to set your rules such as `$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');` and if they all validate then `$this->form_validation->run()` will return true. The documentation has a great explanation for how it works, with examples.

Comment: Okay. So I download the code. Move all the files to the appropriate folders. Set the keys in the config/recaptcha.php file. Then where I have my form submit logic I put in the $this->form_validation->run() function. Then in the HTML I do what?? I need to display the captcha for user input. I see google's code for adding the php recaptcha into non-code igniter documents, but I'm not sure which parts of that are relevant. And I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be making calls to particular files.  Right now I have

Comment: `<? $this->load->view('recaptcha.php');
            $publickey = "thekeynumbersandgibberish";                  echo get_html($publickey); ?>`  this currently breaks my HTML page, I figure I'm not calling the file and function correctly using code igniter syntax. What is the proper syntax? This was not included in the code igniter documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have my on idea how recaptcha works on Codigniter. I cannot explain it to you clearly but I hope you can understand this codes below:

Add this to your config files

```
#google reCaptcha
$config['recaptcha_sitekey'] = 'put site key'; //Recaptcha Site key
$config['recaptcha_secretkey'] = 'put secret key'; //Recaptcha Secret Key
```

Add this code to your validation form

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('g-recaptcha-response', 'recaptcha validation', 'required|callback_validate_captcha');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Please check the the captcha form');
```

and dont forget to add this to the controller where the recaptcha will validate

```
//ADDITIONAL CODES
    function validate_captcha() {
        $captcha = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$this->config->item('recaptcha_sitekey')."&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        if ($response . 'success' == false) {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Add this codes to the form where recaptcha will appear

```
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $this->config->item('recaptcha_sitekey') ?>"></div>
```

And don`t forget the Javascript

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

And if you want to appear recaptcha twice from main page to modal add this code to your modal

```
<script>
    createRecaptcha();
    function createRecaptcha() {
    grecaptcha.render("captcha", {sitekey: "<?php echo $this->config->item('recaptcha_sitekey') ?>", theme: "light"});
    }
</script>
```

add this code for where you want recaptcha will appear

```
<div id="captcha"></div>
```

This is all I can do  ^_^

Demo: https://www.waraywarayako.ph/